# Closing windows on Canvas, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to come up with a solution to this problem.
I need to detect a mouse click on the little red rectangle for window closing.
That clicked window should close only if there isn't some other window 'on top of it'.

I thought of detecting a click on red color, but that doesn't work really well.

PS. I can't use pop up windows, they need to be done like this.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="open">
    Open new window:
    Height = <input type="text" id="txt_height">, width = 
    <input type="text" id="txt_width"> <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="close"> Closing window
    <br> <br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas> <br> <br>
    Currently, there are <span id="details_1"></span> windows open. <br>
    <span id="details_2"></span>

    <script>
        var A = 0;
        var i = 0;
        $("#details_1").text(i);

        $('input[type=radio]').click(function(e) {
            var value = $(this).val(); 
            if(this.id === 'open') A=1;
            if(this.id === 'close') A=2;
        });

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        function mouse_position(canvas, event){
            const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = Math.floor(event.clientX - rect.left);
            const y = Math.floor(event.clientY - rect.top);   
            
            if ( A === 1 )  open(x,y);
            if ( A === 2 )  close();
        }

        $('#canvas').click(function(e){ mouse_position(canvas, event);})    

        function open(x,y){
            i++;
            var width = $("#txt_width").val();
            var height = $("#txt_height").val();
            var new_x = x + (width - 30);

            if( !width.match(/^\d+$/) || !height.match(/^\d+$/)) alert('Natural numbers only!');
        
            if ( height < 30) alert('Must be greater than 30!'); 

            ctx.restore();
            ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.save();

            ctx.rect(x, y, width, 30);
            ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, 30); 
            ctx.font = "15px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillText("Window no. " + i, x + 10, y + 20); 
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.save();

            ctx.rect(new_x, y, 30, 30);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(new_x, y, 30, 30);
            ctx.font = "15px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fillText("X", new_x + 10, y + 20);            
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.save();

            $("#details_1").text(i);
            $("#details_2").text('Those are: ');
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
                $("#details_2").append('Window ' + (j+1) + ' ');
        }

        function close(){
            //need help here
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler example :

```js
var canvas, ctx;

var win_list = [];
var A = 0;
var cnt = 0, i = 0;

function win (width, height) {
  
  var x = 0, y = 0;
  return {'id':++i, 'name':"Window no. "+i
         ,'open':open, 'show':show
         ,'isInside':isInside, 'isInsideClose':isInsideClose};

  function open (xx,yy) {
    x = xx; y = yy;
    this.show();
    return this;
  }

  function show () {

    ctx.save();

    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height); 
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, height);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, 30); 
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.strokeRect(x, y, width, 30);
    ctx.font = '15px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText(this.name, x+10, y+20); 

    var new_x = x + (width - 30);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(new_x, y, 30, 30);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.strokeRect(new_x, y, 30, 30);
    ctx.font = '15px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('X', new_x+10, y+20);            

    ctx.restore();

    return this;
  }

  function isInside (xx, yy) {
    return x <= xx && xx < x+width && y <= yy && yy < y+width;        
  }

  function isInsideClose (xx, yy) {
    var new_x = x + (width - 30);
    return new_x <= xx && xx < x+width && y <= yy && yy < y+width;        
  }
}

function mouse_position (event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = Math.floor(event.clientX - rect.left);
  const y = Math.floor(event.clientY - rect.top); 
  
  if ( A === 1 )  create_win(x,y);
  if ( A === 2 )  close(x,y);
}

function create_win (x, y) {

  var width = $('#txt_width').val();
  var height = $('#txt_height').val();

  if (! width.match(/^\d+$/) || !height.match(/^\d+$/)) 
    alert("Natural numbers only!");
        
  if (height < 30) 
    alert("Must be greater than 30!"); 

  var w = win(width, height).open(x, y);
  win_list.push(w);

  $("#details_1").text(win_list.length);
  $("#details_2").append(' '+w.name);
}

function close (x, y) {
  //need help here
  var j;

  for (j = win_list.length - 1; j >= 0 ; --j) {
    let w = win_list[j];

    if (w.isInside(x, y)) {
      if (w.isInsideClose(x, y)) {
        break;           
      }
      return;
    }
  }

  if (j < 0) return;

  for (; j < win_list.length-1 ; ++j) {
    win_list[j] = win_list[j+1];
  }
  win_list.pop();

  redraw_all();
}

function redraw_all () {
   ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600); 

   win_list.forEach(function (w) {w.show();});

   $("#details_1").text(win_list.length);

   $("#details_2").text("Those are: ");
   win_list.forEach(function (w) {
     $("#details_2").append(' '+w.name);
   });
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

  Height = <input type="text" id="txt_height" value="100"><br>
  Width = <input type="text" id="txt_width" value="200"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="open"> Open new window <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="close"> Closing window <br>
  <br>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
  <br>
  Currently, there are <span id="details_1"></span> windows open. <br>
  <span id="details_2"></span>

  <script>
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $("#details_1").text(0);
    $("#details_2").text("Those are: ");

    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(e) {
      if (this.id === 'open') A=1;
      if (this.id === 'close') A=2;
    });

    $('#canvas').click(function(e){ 
      mouse_position(e); 
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Windows GUIs, focus, and trees

I would like to say its easy. No matter how you implement a windowing system it gets complicated very quickly.

Windows GUIs like the DOM are build as a tree, eg the desktop contains windows, windows contain title bars and the title bar contains the close icon.

In the example below I implement a very basic tree structure and various types of elements. As all elements share a lot of the same behavior and as I personal will not use the class syntax (until it is fixed properly) the elements are build add hock.

### Behavior

- The click event searches the root element tree for clicked items.
- Items are sorted visually with the focused window at the top.
- If a window element is clicked and it is not in focus that window will be focused.
- If a window element is clicked and it is in focus and the clicked item is a close button that window will be closed and the next in visual order will get focus.
- If the top most item (canvas) is clicked a new window is created.
- The top most element (root) is called `desktopCanvas`. It is via this element that you open, close, focus, and query click events.

Normally all the actions would drive an event queue, but in the example I have not implemented such.

All items are built from the `CanvasElement` and the `CanvasElement` is assigned the properties and methods to implement a tree structure, basic rendering. You pass the Object type you want the element to be. Eg `const element = new CanvasElement(new Area(0, 0, this.w, 30), MenuBar, undefined, name)` creates an element of type `MenuBar`. You add it to a window via `cWindow.add(element)`

See example for more.

### Example

Click canvas to create windows. Click window to focus window. Click close on focused window to close. You can not close a window until it has focus.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const canBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.addEventListener("click", mouseEvent);
function mouseEvent(event) {
    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;
    const found = desktopCanvas.findClicked(x, y);
    if (found === desktopCanvas) {
        const wx = x < canvas.width - 200 ? x : canvas.width - 200;
        const wy = y < canvas.height - 200 ? y : canvas.height - 200;
        desktopCanvas.open(new CanvasElement(new Area(wx , wy, 200, 200), CanvasWindow, undefined, "Window"));
    } else if (found) {
        const top = found.topParent();
        if (found.name === "close" && top.focused) { desktopCanvas.close(top) }
        else { desktopCanvas.focus(top) }
    }
}
const tree = {
    get children() { return [] },
    add(child, top = false) {
         child.parent = this;
         if (top) { this.children.unshift(child) }
         else { this.children.push(child) }
    },
    remove(child) {
        const idx = this.children.indexOf(child);
        if (idx > -1) {
           this.children.splice(idx, 1);
           return true;
        }
        for (const c of this.children) {
           if (c.remove(child)) { return true }
        }
    },
    eachChild(cb, ...data) {
        if (typeof cb === "string") {
            for (const c of this.children) {c[cb](...data) }
            return;
        }
        for (const c of this.children) { cb(c) }
    },
    topParent() {
        var top = this;
        while (top.top !== true) { top = top.parent }
        return top;
    },
}
function Area(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}
function CanvasElement(area, type = {}, name, ...data) {
    Object.assign(this, type);
    name !== undefined && (this.name = name);
    Object.assign(this, area);
    Object.assign(this, tree);
    this.init(...data);
}
CanvasElement.prototype = {
    init() {},
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.save();
        this.transform(ctx);
        this.drawBorder(ctx);
        if (this.drawContent) { this.drawContent(ctx) }
        this.eachChild("draw", ctx);
        ctx.restore();
    },
    drawBorder(ctx) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    transform(ctx) { ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, this.x, this.y) },
    isInside(x, y) { return x > this.x && x < this.x + this.w && y > this.y && y < this.y + this.h },
    findClicked(x, y) {
        var idx = this.children.length;
        if (this.isInside(x, y)) {
            while (idx-- > 0) {  // from top to bottom visually 
                const child = this.children[idx];
                const found = child.findClicked(x - this.x, y - this.y);
                if (found) { return found }
            }
            return this;
        }
    },
}
const CloseIcon = {
    name : "close",
    drawContent(ctx) {
        const {w,h} = this;
        ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font = "16px arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStyle = this.parent.parent.focused ? "#FFF" : "#000";
        ctx.fillText("X", w / 2, h / 2);
    },
}
const MenuBar = {
    name : "menuBar",
    init(text) {
        this.text = text;
        const bar = new Area(this.w - 18, 0, 18, 18);
        this.add(new CanvasElement(bar, CloseIcon));
    },
    drawContent() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.parent.focused ? "#CCC" : "#999";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font = "16px arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStyle =  "#000";
        ctx.fillText(this.text, this.w / 2, this.h / 2 + 2);
    },
}
const CanvasWindow = {
    name: "window",
    top: true,
    init(name) {
        this.name = name;
        const bar = new Area(0, 0, this.w, 18);
        this.add(new CanvasElement(bar, MenuBar, undefined, name))
    },
    drawContent() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.focused ? "#FFF" : "#EEE";
        ctx.fill();
    },
}
const Desktop = {
    name: "desk",
    focuse: undefined,
    init(ctx) {
        this.w = ctx.canvas.width;
        this.h = ctx.canvas.height;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    },
    draw() {
        this.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1, 0, 0)
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
        if (this.drawContent) { this.drawContent(this.ctx) }
        this.eachChild("draw", this.ctx);
    },
    close(item) {
        this.remove(item);
        if(this.focuse && this.focuse === item) {
            if (this.children.length) { this.focus(this.children[this.children.length - 1]) } 
            else {  this.focuse = undefined }
        }
        desktopCanvas.draw(); 
    },
    open(item) { this.focus(item) },
    focus(item) {
        this.remove(item);
        this.add(item);
        if(this.focuse) {
            this.focuse.focused = false;
            this.focuse = undefined;
        }
        item.focused = true;
        this.focuse = item;
        this.draw(); 
    }
}
const desktopCanvas = new CanvasElement(new Area( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width), Desktop, "desktop", ctx);
desktopCanvas.open(new CanvasElement(new Area(10 , 10, 200, 200), CanvasWindow, undefined, "Example window"));
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Click canvas to create windows. Click window to focus window. Click close on focused window to close. You can not close a window until it has focus.